# Objective C memory leak problem

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I have the memory leak problem in the following objective c code. The <s>bold</s>asterisked(`***`) line is the line with memory leak (mentioned in instrument).  Any idea of it?  Thanks.

```
- (UIImage*)part:(float)part ofImage:(UIImage*)imgObject withMask:(UIImage*)imgMask {
 UIImage *imgResult = nil;
 CGRect rcMask = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, imgMask.size.width, imgMask.size.height);
 CGRect rcObject = CGRectMake(0.5f * (rcMask.size.width - imgObject.size.width), 0.0f, imgObject.size.width, imgObject.size.height * part);

 BytePtr pictureData = (BytePtr)malloc(rcMask.size.width * rcMask.size.height * 4);
 CGContextRef pictureContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(pictureData, rcMask.size.width,              rcMask.size.height,8, rcMask.size.width * 4,CGImageGetColorSpace(imgObject.CGImage),              kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

 CGContextClipToMask(pictureContext, rcMask, imgMask.CGImage);
 CGImageRef imgInRect;
 imgInRect = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imgObject.CGImage, rcObject);
 CGContextDrawImage(pictureContext, rcObject, imgInRect);
 CGImageRelease(imgInRect);
 ***imgResult = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(pictureContext)];***

 CGContextRelease(pictureContext);
 free(pictureData);
 return imgResult;
}
```

Comment: You should properly format your code in the text editor on this site.

Comment: Figured it out.  The boldness disappeared on Jacob's edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
imgResult = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(pictureContext)];
```

You create a `CGImage`, pass it to a `UIImage` factory method, and then forget about it. You're leaking the `CGImage`.

Do this instead:

```
CGImageRef cgResult = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(pictureContext);
if (cgResult) {
    imgResult = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: cgResult];
    CGImageRelease(cgResult);
}
```